# Read words from .txt, and count for each words

Tags: python, file

I wonder, how to read character string like fscanf. I need to read for word, in the all .txt .  **I need a count for each words.**

```
collectwords = collections.defaultdict(int)

with open('DatoSO.txt', 'r') as filetxt:

for line in filetxt:
    v=""
    for char in line:
        if str(char) != " ":
          v=v+str(char)

        elif str(char) == " ":
          collectwords[v] += 1
          v=""
```

this way, I cant to read the last word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also consider using `collections.counter` if you are using Python >=2.7

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

It adds a number of methods like 'most_common', which might be useful in this type of application.

From Doug Hellmann's PyMOTW:

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter()
with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        c.update(line.rstrip().lower())

print 'Most common:'
for letter, count in c.most_common(3):
    print '%s: %7d' % (letter, count)
```

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/collections/counter.html -- although this does letter counts instead of word counts. In the `c.update` line, you would want to replace `line.rstrip().lower` with `line.split()` and perhaps some code to get rid of punctuation.

**Edit:**  To remove punctuation here is probably the fastest solution:

```
import collections
import string

c = collections.Counter()
with open('DataSO.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        c.update(line.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation).split())
```

(borrowed from the following question [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python))

Answer (score 3):

Uhm, like this?

```
with open('DatoSO.txt', 'r') as filetxt:
    for line in filetxt:
        for word in line.split():
            collectwords[word] += 1
```

Comment: its good. but when I print :'shoes': 1, 'shoes\n': 5,"  shoes with \n. without \n.

Comment: You might want to throw a `word.strip()` in then (`collectwords[word.strip()] += 1`) to remove any additional white space around it.

Comment: Changing `split(' ')` to `split()` would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

Python makes this easy:

```
collectwords = []
filetxt = open('DatoSO.txt', 'r')

for line in filetxt:
  collectwords.extend(line.split())
```

Comment: I think he wants to count the number of occurrences though.