# How to find the number of occurrance of each word in a file using python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read words from .txt, and count for each words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452550/read-words-from-txt-and-count-for-each-words)
>   [Python script to find word frequencies of a given document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480000/python-script-to-find-word-frequencies-of-a-given-document)

There is one file having some data in it. I would like to get each and every word without repetition and want to get number of occurance of that word. How do I write a python program for this?

Comment: Using any text editor.... seriously, what have you tried?

Comment: First, read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), then try to write your program. If you have any problems come back here and ask a specific question.

Comment: Is there a particular part that you're having a problem with?  Or do you just want someone to write your program for you?